# Is the number of vertices of a convex $d-$dimensional lattice polytop without interior lattice points bounded?

Tags: nt.number-theory, convex-polytopes

The lattice polytop $[0,n_1]\times[0,n_2]\times\dots\times[0,n_{d-1}]\times[0,1]$ contains
$(n_1+1)(n_2+1)\cdots(n_{d-1}+1)2$ integral points on the boundary and no integral points in
its interior. Its number of vertices, $2^d$, is however bounded by a function depending only
on its dimension $d$. Does there exist a sequence of convex $d-$dimensional lattice-polytops without interior
lattice points and more and more vertices?

Remarks: (1) The answer is no in dimension $2$.

(2) This question is motivated by a result of Lagarias-Ziegler who showed that the volume
(and thus the number of vertices) of a convex $d-$dimensional lattice polytop is bounded if
it contains exactly $k>0$ interior lattice points. If no sequence as above exist, then 
the condition on the existence of $k$ interior lattice points can perhaps be modified 
into a condition on the number of integral vertices (which has to be sufficiently large) and integral boundary points.

Comment: Why not take a polygonal prism?  Depending on the polygon, you can get twice the number of vertices of the (d-1)- dimensional polygon. Or am I forgetting something?  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2012.02.09

Comment: The more I look at the question, the more one thing becomes clear: at least one of us has not had enough coffee this morning.  Gerhard "It's Quite Possible Its Me" Paseman, 2012.02.09

Comment: Interestingly, it is known that there are only a finite number of
*maximal* hollow lattice polytopes in a fixed dimension, where "maximal hollow" means "not properly contained in a larger hollow lattice polytope" (Averkov, Wagner, Weismantel; Nill & Ziegler).

Comment: I think that ask me about system design provided an answer to the question: in dimensions ≥3, the number of vertices is not bounded.

Comment: Joseph, if it is not too much trouble, would you leave a comment enlightening me (and future readers) briefly on hollow polytopes?  A rough idea or Wikipedia link would suffice.  Gerhard "Enquiring Minds Want To Know" Paseman, 2012.02.09

Comment: Gerhard Paseman's answer ends the question and Joseph O'Rourke's remark shows that there is probably no interesting variation. Thank you.

Comment: @Gerhard: Sorry, I neglected to define *hollow*: a polytope is hollow if it does not contain any lattice points in its interior. So it is exactly Roland's concept.  There is another concept, "empty," which is generally taken to mean that the only lattice points are the vertices, i.e., not even any in the interior of a face/facet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Encouraged by Andre Henriques' comment (and not seeing a response which puts more constraints on the problem), I shall promote my comment to an answer.

Consider an arbitrary convex polygon P in R^2 which has n vertices for your favorite sufficiently large positive integer n.  Then P x [0,1] (or an appropriate represntation) is a convex polytope in R^3 with no interior lattice points and 2n vertices. It should be easy to extend this example to higher dimensions.  Thus a sequence of such polytopes with unbounded number of vertices exists in R^d for any fixed d with d > 2.

Gerhard "Had Enough Coffee This Morning" Paseman, 2012.02.09

Comment: You are absolutely right. 

Comment: An interesting follow up question (especiially for d=2) is to ask for the fewest number of lattice points enclosed by a polygon with n vertices, and use this to examine larger dimension polytopes where most of the lattice points are at the vertices.  I invite you to ask a well formulated version of this.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2012.02.09  